# What is the mechanism for trans-stilbene to stilbene dibromide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, halogenation

What is the mechanism for *trans*-stilbene to stilbene dibromide?

[image: trans-stilbene to stilbene dibromide]

This is what I know:

The bond between the hydrogen and bromine is broken and the bromine is given a negative charge, while the $\ce{H}$ protonates the double bond between the two $\ce{Ph}$ groups. After that, I am unsure what the $\ce{H2O2}$ does

Comment: What is the role of the peroxide? What are your thoughts?  You need to make some effort to answer this or it will be closed.

Comment: @Waylander The bond between the hydrogen and bromine is broken and the bromine is given a negative charge while the h protonates the double bond between the two Ph groups. After that, I am unsure what the H2O2 does as well as the purpose of ethanol

Comment: Etahnol is just the solvent. What is hydrogen peroxide usually used for? If you look at the product stilbene dibromide you will see the trans configuration of the Br atoms, does this remind you of any other form of addition to a double bond?

Comment: @Waylander Doesn't hydrogen peroxide add an OH group to the molecule? Also, isn't addition of H2O2 a syn addition?

Comment: You know what syn addition is and don't know that H2O2 is oxidant?

Answer (score 2):

The key feature in the product that shows what is going on is the *trans* configuration of the two bromines. This is characteristic of the addition of elemental bromine *via* a brominium ion [mechanism here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/reaction-guide/bromination-of-alkenes-with-br2-to-give-dibromides/).

So where does the Br2 come from as we started with HBr? This is where the hydrogen peroxide comes in. It is well documented [example here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5266295A/en) that hydrogen peroxide  oxidises hydrogen bromide to bromine. This transformation can take place in the presence of an activated alkene such as stilbene.