# Why is halohydrin not formed In bromination of stilbene?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Stilbene can be dibrominated using $\ce{HBr}$ and hydrogen peroxide in ethanol.  Common sense would suggest that the major product should be the bromo-ethoxy product due to reaction with bromonium ion followed by the solvent since it outnumbers the strong nucleophile.  But, in practice this is not seen, or only seen in very small amounts.  Why is this?

Comment: [What is the mechanism for trans-stilbene to stilbene dibromide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/123178/125117)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [reference 2](https://d.web.umkc.edu/drewa/chem321l/handouts/lab10x2additiontoalkenesfs2010.pdf), both *anti*- and *syn*-products are formed, so your intuition may be correct, and you may, partly, be proposing the *correct* mechanism for the dibromination of stilbene.

---

Reagents produce $\ce{Br2}$ *in-situ*:

$$
\ce{2HBr + H2O2 -> Br2 + 2H2O}
$$

This reaction mechanism may be favorable at lower concentrations of $\ce{HBr}$. However, according to several references (e.g., 1, [2](https://d.web.umkc.edu/drewa/chem321l/handouts/lab10x2additiontoalkenesfs2010.pdf)), an appreciable concentration of $\ce{HBr}$ is required for dibromination of stilbene.

Moreover, bromide ion, being negatively charged, is a better nucleophile than ethanol, being neutral. Thus, you might expect your product to react again to form ***syn***-dibromo product, due to anti ethanol addition followed by $\mathrm{S_N}2$:

[image: mechanism of syn dibromination of stilbene in ethanol bromine hydrogen peroxide]

Both *anti*- and *syn*-products are formed, so your intuition may be correct; however, *anti*-product is more favorable at the commonly used concentrations.

[image: green chemical dibromination of stilbene with ethanol and peroxide]

Typically, 70% yield is obtained in the experiment.$^\text{1}$

#### References

1. McKenzie, L. C., Huffman, L. M., and Hutchison, J. E. (2005). The Evolution of a Green Chemistry Laboratory Experiment: Greener Brominations of Stilbene. *J. Chem. Educ.*, *82*(*2*), 306-310 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ed082p306).
2. Kilway, K. V., Horn, J. D. V.(2006), X2 Addition to Alkenes: Bromination of trans-Stilbene. Available as [PDF](https://d.web.umkc.edu/drewa/chem321l/handouts/lab10x2additiontoalkenesfs2010.pdf).

Comment: In both of first two schemes, the ethoxy function has extra carbon. Would you correct it as soon as possible?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne thank you for the suggestion, have made corrections; I made some changes in the second mechanism as well.

Comment: Again, 3rd structure of 1st scheme has peroxide addition (shouln't oxygen have plus charge) instead of ethanol addition. Also, if $\ce{HBr}$ leaves, 4th structure of 1st scheme should not have hydrogen on oxygen.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne thank you again, must be that I am not very familiar with the software.

Comment: Still, 3rd structure of 1st scheme has peroxide addition instead of ethanol addition. It can easily fix by putting Et for OH.